# Count non-blank cells based on arrayformula in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to get a count of all non-blank cells in a column that belong to a certain market. The formula I'm using (and that is not working) is:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(('GR Live Campaign Tracker'!$J$3:$J$8607,"US")*(mmult(not(isblank('GR Live Campaign Tracker'!$M$3:$M$8607))))))
```

I also tried:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(('GR Live Campaign Tracker'!$J$3:$J$8607,"US")*(''GR Live Campaign Tracker'!$M$3:$M$8607)))
```

which also did not work.

Column J contains countries (e.g. US, UK, Brazil), while column M is either blank or contains a number and I would need to retrieve a count of all cells that contain a number for each market.

Comment: Best is to share a doc with us.

Comment: Ok. I have shared a sheet here with two tabs. One contains the two columns I am trying to work with (GR Live Campaign Tracker) and one the formulas I have added. [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AgsidOZBOczhdFVVa1lkSWh6REZSUTM2b0lTQ0tvU1E&usp=sharing)

Comment: Any ideas? Anything would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following formula to accomplish that.

### Formula

```
=QUERY(
   'GR Live Campaign Tracker'!J:L,                          // data range
   "SELECT J, COUNT(L)  WHERE L IS NOT NULL GROUP BY J",    // select
    0                                                       // headers
)
```

### Screenshot

[image]

### Example

Added the formula into your example file.

Comment: Only question now: It seems to count duplicates. Can something like "CountUnique" be added if it is done in this way?

Comment: @Chris That's a different question, please re-ask and put the expected outcome next to column E if you like....